# .htaccess URL-redirect

Tags: url, redirect, apache2, web-testing

I am having some issues with redirecting URL's on my website after migrating to new HOST.
I have set up two langauges. EN & SE.

I have not yet changed the DNS/Nameservers as I want to test the website on the new host.

When accesing [www.HOSTIP.com/customers](http://www.HOSTIP.com/customers) after the migration, the url redirects to [www.HOSTIP.com/**se**/customers](http://www.HOSTIP.com/**se**/customers).

The **/se/** is correct and works on the old host.

On the new host I am however redirected to 404:
*Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.*

I believe this i controlled in the .htaccess file.
Find the htaccess config down below.

```
RewriteEngine on

#Capture the language string and present it as the variable
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z]{2})/(.*)
RewriteRule ^.* %2?language=%1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And this is how I get my lang in php:

```
$lang = $_GET["language"];
if (!$lang) {
    header("Location: /se" . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);
    exit();
}
```

So in other words, the redirect /se/ works on the old host, but not on the new host.
All the files has been placed in the exact same "place" on the new host.

Would anyone know what might be the problem here?

I have tried editing the apache2.conf AllowOverride All. This however crashes the site.
Tried replacing/removing the https as the new server is not yet configured for https.

Comment: What's in your Apache error.log ?

Comment: 1) What exists at `http://www.hostip.com/se/customers`? 2) Is there an `index.php`? 3) The file system layout is the same points to a configuration problem. Post the `<VirtualHost`> configuration for the site and `.htaccess` file. 4) Create a `curl` CLI request with the language header and post the request and response including headers. 5) Look up the `access.log` and `error.log` for that request and post the details. 6) Are you using vanilla PHP or PHP-FPM and which version? 7) To solve this problem you must understand the Apache configuration, request, response, and error log entry.